# How to use embedded document to save hierarchical form fields data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a project and choosen mongodb for database. On it I have a form with following structure

[image]

Here it will save the details in database and will be checked on frontend if form 1 is enabled or not for Home cleaning etc. for this I have planned to save form ids in embedded document but I am not sure if its a good method to save it, I have selected embedded document because we can filter or compare directly. Other way is to save ids comma separated or as json object but then I will not be able to filter it directly and will have to fetch all ids and compare in code.

I have gone through the articles and they recommend it but my concern is, is it good to use embedded document for single value like here ?

Any help or explanation is appreciable.

example

```
{
id:1,
industry_id:1,
status:1,
forms:[{form_id:1},
      {form_id:2}
      ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not obvious what is the "single value" here. Show an example document that would back this screen.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes its not much clear but as a beginner I am not sure how should I explain it more and I have not created the database yet so cant share the sample.

Comment: I have added a example in question, may you will have idea what I am trying to say.